# Error while booting v0.4.1-stable - nouveau, nomodeset not working

Tags: boot, system, acpi

I installed my ElementaryOS with Rufus 2.16 on my USB, and tried to launch it. But then appeared this error:

[image]

I tried using every option from F6 menu, and still not working.
My PC: 
 1. i5-3470;
 2. EVGA GTX970 SC;
 3. GoodRam DDR3 8GB 1333MHz;
 4. Gigabyte Z77-D3H;

Answer (score 0):

Did you check for the hash sum of the iso file after you downloaded it?
In Windows do: `CertUtil -hashfile <PATH_TO_THE_ISO_FILE> SHA256`
In Linux do: `sha256sum elementaryos-xxxxxxxxxx.iso`

It should match this string:
`1d85b675bbbfc868d2286718cdc62590e41e1b40bfffcef7ac4111b7ea7da905`

Comment: Yeah, I did it, was 100% correct.

Comment: I used same iso file now on VM and it worked correct.

Comment: well it could be your GPU then. nvidias are known to have screwy driver support. are you able to remove your nvidia GPU and use your integrated one?